# Python find duplicates rows but they are not

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with my pandas dataframe. Pandas detects duplicated rows, but there are none.
I wanted to use the pivot function but I have the error message “ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape”.
So I tried to find the duplicated rows in my dataframe and when I used the duplicated() function the result were :

```
            Number_id   [...]         Name        Value
  802       001         [...]         Name1       41
  809       001         [...]         Name2       75
  813       001         [...]         Name3       13
  845       001         [...]         Name4       2
```

Obviously, those rows are not the same, for each row : Number_id, value and name are different.

My dataframe dimensions are [860 rows x 10 columns]. There are 215 Number_id, each Number_id has 4 values, one for each name. 215*4=860

I wanted to use the pivot function like this :

```
df.pivot(index=list_of_index_columns, columns='Name', values='Value')
```

The list_of_index_columns correspond to all the column of the df except Name and Value, so 8 columns.

I don’t how to handle this. Can I have some help?

I use the Spyder 3.8 version.

Comment: could you add a sample of your original data frame and the exact code you used to get the duplicates?

Comment: By default `duplicated` only returns `True` for the duplicated rows, so looking at the duplicated rows they might _seem_ unique. You'd want `.duplicated(keep=False)` to see both the first instance of the row and all rows which are duplicates. Regardless the fact that `.duplicated` is returning _something_ means that you **do** have duplicates.

Comment: To get the duplicate i used :

dup = var[var.duplicated()]print("\n", "!!!ici!!!", "\n",dup[["reference","nom de l abonnement"]], "\n","!!!ici!!!","\n")

Answer (score 0):

There is duplication in your data. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['0','0','C','0','E','0'],
    ['A','0','0','0','0','F'],
    ['A','0','0','0','0','F'],
    ['0','0','C','D','0','0'],
    ['A','B','0','0','0','0']], columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
)
df[df.duplicated()]
```

[image]

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

[image]